# JWSGI on Ubuntu Focal

Tags: java, jvm, uwsgi, java-11

I am trying to run the example from [uwsgi-doc](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/JWSGI.html)
I am running Ubuntu Focal (completely fresh install [VM])
here is everything that i install

```
aptitude install uwsgi-plugin-jvm-openjdk-11 uwsgi-plugin-jwsgi-openjdk-11
```

but when i try to run the examples i get

> [...]
> JVM 11.0.14+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu2.20.04 initialized at 0x555b6858c348 (worker: 1 pid: 5177)
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: uwsgi
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: uwsgi
> at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
> at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)

i am trying to run this code (it does compile)

```
import java.util.*;
public class MyApp {

    public static Object[] application(HashMap env) {

        int status = 200;

        HashMap<String,Object> headers = new HashMap<String,Object>();
        headers.put("Content-type", "text/html");
        // a response header can have multiple values
        String[] servers = {"uWSGI", "Unbit"};
        headers.put("Server", servers);

        String body = "<h1>Hello World</h1>" + env.get("REQUEST_URI");

        Object[] response = { status, headers, body };

        return response;
    }
}
```

with the command

```
./uwsgi --socket /tmp/uwsgi.socket --plugins jvm,jwsgi --jwsgi MyApp:application --threads 40
```

but even running this command (without the class and method specified)

```
uwsgi --socket /tmp/uwsgi.socket --plugins jvm,jwsgi --threads 40
```

i get the exact same error....

anyone know why that is?
or what i am doing wrong?

thx in advance!

Answer (score 0):

sorry, figured it out there is a --jvm-classpath switch and a uwsgi.jar at
/usr/share/java/uwsgi.jar

my bad, sorry!